# Magento 2 configure stock by website

Tags: magento2, product, admin, configuration, quantity

I configured a store with multiple websites on Magento 2.
Each website is a different country or region and each website must manage it's own product quantity

I set quantity_and_stock_status attribute scope to website in Stores/Attributes/Product, but when I edit quantity in product detail under specific store view the value is saved for all views.

An example
Two website: Italy and UK, 
Two stores: Milan under Italy with Milan StoreView, Manchester under UK with Manchester StoreView.

I select a product and select Manchester StoreView, edit quantity to a value (i.e 10) and save, the same quantity is reported in Milan StoreView.
Near Quantity and Stock value is reported [STORE VIEW] scope and Use Default Value is unchecked.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say something wrong, but I think it is not native in Magento. Anyway, I some modules do exactly what you want, if I understood correctly :
[Advanced Inventory](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?q=advanced%20inventory&pl=0)

Answer (score 0):

Currently Magento 2 does not support this.  However there is a feature request languishing within the Magento 2 github repo where the expectation is that this may be delivered post 2.1.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/473